# how do i parse a csv file to grab the column names first then the rows that relate to it?

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

here is my csv

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5
column1_row1,column2_row1,column3_row1,column4_row1,column5_row1
column1_row2,column2_row2,column3_row2,column4_row2,column5_row2
column1_row3,column2_row3,column3_row3,column4_row3,column5_row3
column1_row4,column2_row4,column3_row4,column4_row4,column5_row4
column1_row5,column2_row5,column3_row5,column4_row5,column5_row5
column1_row6,column2_row6,column3_row6,column4_row6,column5_row6
column1_row7,column2_row7,column3_row7,column4_row7,column5_row7
column1_row8,column2_row8,column3_row8,column4_row8,column5_row8
column1_row9,column2_row9,column3_row9,column4_row9,column5_row9
```

first row is the column names of course. i tried fgetcsv() but all that would do is display all rows. rather than what i want. how can i do it?

so if i were to put the data into an array at the end i would be able print out a table format of the data just like its shown in excel.

thanks

this is my sample:

```
$filename = "upload/sample.csv";
if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {
       print_r($row);
     }
}
```

this is my output: (i put the $row into a pre so i can show it)

```
Array
(
    [0] => column1
    [1] => column2
    [2] => column3
    [3] => column4
    [4] => column5
column1_row1
    [5] => column2_row1
    [6] => column3_row1
    [7] => column4_row1
    [8] => column5_row1
column1_row2
    [9] => column2_row2
    [10] => column3_row2
    [11] => column4_row2
    [12] => column5_row2
column1_row3
    [13] => column2_row3
    [14] => column3_row3
    [15] => column4_row3
    [16] => column5_row3
column1_row4
    [17] => column2_row4
    [18] => column3_row4
    [19] => column4_row4
    [20] => column5_row4
column1_row5
    [21] => column2_row5
    [22] => column3_row5
    [23] => column4_row5
    [24] => column5_row5
column1_row6
    [25] => column2_row6
    [26] => column3_row6
    [27] => column4_row6
    [28] => column5_row6
column1_row7
    [29] => column2_row7
    [30] => column3_row7
    [31] => column4_row7
    [32] => column5_row7
column1_row8
    [33] => column2_row8
    [34] => column3_row8
    [35] => column4_row8
    [36] => column5_row8
column1_row9
    [37] => column2_row9
    [38] => column3_row9
    [39] => column4_row9
    [40] => column5_row9
)
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `fgetcsv` and then walking through each line?

Comment: can you show me a sample of your method? then i'll point out what confuses me

Comment: I don't really have a sample. Can you show yours and what doesn't work?

Comment: Does it help if you set the enclosure (which defaults to ") to something else? Like null or an empty string or something like that?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

For reading it all at once you can use:

```
$csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file("file1.csv",FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
$keys = array_shift($csv);
```

To turn all the rows into a nice associative array you could then apply:

```
foreach ($csv as $i=>$row) {
    $csv[$i] = array_combine($keys, $row);
}
```

Comment: How can I use this with a `;` as seperator?

Comment: This way you cannot deal with line breakers in a cell.

Comment: @Michiel, how to use a different separator: `$file = file("file1.csv",FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$csv = array_map("str_getcsv",$file, array_fill(0, count($file), ';'));`

Comment: @mario this falls into my favorite category of answers. short, works as advertised and most important it teaches me new functionality

Comment: Note this only works if all of your data rows are the same length as the header row.

Answer (score 7):

```
// Opening the file for reading...
$fp = fopen('path_to_your_file.csv', 'r');

// Headrow
$head = fgetcsv($fp, 4096, ';', '"');

// Rows
while($column = fgetcsv($fp, 4096, ';', '"'))
{
    // This is a great trick, to get an associative row by combining the headrow with the content-rows.
    $column = array_combine($head, $column);

    echo $column['column1'];
}
```

Comment: i tried your sample but i didnt get an output. know why that would be?

Comment: only works if your column-names are 'column1', 'column2', etc. like in your example. `echo $column['the_name_of_your_column_in_the_headrow'];`

Comment: yea i did , nothing came out so i did a print_r of $column and nothing . here is the pastie http://pastie.org/1796761

Comment: Do you have error_reporting enabled? If not, do it and look if an error occurred. do you reach the while loop? paste an `die(x);` for debugging into the loop to see if it is executed. If not, the file is empty or the filepointer ($fp) is not set (e.g. invalid path).

Comment: Good solution for anyone stuck on pre 5.3

Comment: This is more memory efficient than accepted response.

Answer (score 1):

I made this quick solution using fgetcsv, works fine and it's easier to read and understand. Then the whole result is saved in the $csv array

```
$csv = array();
$i = 0;
if (($handle = fopen($upload['file'], "r")) !== false) {
    $columns = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        $csv[$i] = array_combine($columns, $row);
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do one `fgetcsv` call first to get the headers, and then start a loop to get the rest?

Modified the example found [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). It should write out a table with headers and values following.

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen('test.csv', 'r')) !== FALSE)
{
    echo '<table>';

    // Get headers
    if (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE)
    {
        echo '<tr><th>'.implode('</th><th>', $data).'</th></tr>';
    }

    // Get the rest
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE)
    {
        echo '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', $data).'</td></tr>';
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

Comment: @Sarmen: Added sample. haven't tested it though. let me know if it works.

Comment: ps i added what i was attempting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be taking it all as one line. Perhaps your csv has a different line ending than it should have? At least that's what it looks like in your output. If you look at row 1, column 5 in your result array, it contains a line ending and column 1 in row 2. And the same in the rest. It reads it all in as one line.

> **Note:** If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the [auto_detect_line_endings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings) run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem. -- [fgetscv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

What platform are you on? Either way, check the line endings.

Answer (score 0):

I modified first answer to better handle different column separators

```
if (($handle = fopen("hdbsource/products_stock.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($csv[] = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {}
    fclose($handle);
}
$keys = array_shift($csv);

foreach ($csv as $i=>$row) {
    $csv[$i] = array_combine($keys, $row);
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.