# Convert an indexed array obtained from .csv to an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am reading data from a .csv (which originally comes from an external database) file with fgetcsv. The first line of the .csv file contains the column names, the following rows contain the data.
What I got so far is an array with the column names, and a second array with the rows of of the .csv file (each row as an array).
How can I convert the second array to an associative array with keys being the column names from the first array?

```
// this is for Mac OS X
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);

// the name of the file to read
$fileName = 'WebArtikel_V1-modified.csv';

// open file (get handle to file)
$file = fopen($fileName, 'r');

// the array to store the csv's data
$rawData = array();
// the first line of the csv
$header = array();

$i = 0;
while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 4096, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    //$line is an array of the csv elements
    //print_r($line);
    if($i == 0){
        $header[] = $line;
    } else {
        $rawData[] = $line;
    }
    $i++;
}
fclose($file);
```

Here is the var_dump($header):

> array (size=1)
>     0 => 
>       array (size=50)
>         0 => string 'KHK_EAN' (length=7)
>         1 => string 'StyleNumber' (length=11)
>         2 => string 'StyleName' (length=9)
>         3 => string 'Setname' (length=7)
>         4 => string 'ColorNumber' (length=11)
>         5 => string 'ColorName' (length=9)
>         6 => string 'StyleSize' (length=9)
>         7 => string 'KHK_Artikel' (length=11)
>         8 => string 'PriceNew' (length=8)
>         9 => string 'PriceSale' (length=9)

Note: there is a toplevel array with 1 element which contains another array with the column names.

The $rawData array:

> array (size=3604)
>     0 => 
>       array (size=50)
>         0 => string '4055765008989' (length=13)
>         1 => string '201001001' (length=9)
>         2 => string ' ' (length=1)
>         3 => string 'ACCESS 3' (length=8)
>         4 => string '2942' (length=4)
>         5 => string 'Blau/Marine' (length=11)
>         6 => string '1' (length=1)
>         7 => string '201001001-2942-1' (length=16)
>         8 => string '199,9' (length=5)
>         9 => string '199,9' (length=5)
>   1 => 
>       array (size=50)
>         0 => string '4055765008996' (length=13)
>         1 => string '201001001' (length=9)
>         2 => string ' ' (length=1)
>         3 => string 'ACCESS 3' (length=8)
>         4 => string '3924' (length=4)
>         5 => string 'Beige/Braun' (length=11)
>         6 => string '1' (length=1)
>         7 => string '201001001-3924-1' (length=16)
>         8 => string '199,9' (length=5)
>         9 => string '199,9' (length=5)
>   2 => 
>       array (size=50)
>         0 => string '4055765009047' (length=13)
>         1 => string '201002001' (length=9)
>         2 => string ' ' (length=1)
>         3 => string 'ACCESS 3' (length=8)
>         4 => string '2942' (length=4)
>         5 => string 'Blau/Marine' (length=11)
>         6 => string '1' (length=1)
>         7 => string '201002001-2942-1' (length=16)
>         8 => string '179,9' (length=5)
>         9 => string '179,9' (length=5)

Note: same as above, nested arrays, so I can't use array_combine().
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the same question as here? Copying it below for convenience.

[how do i parse a csv file to grab the column names first then the rows that relate to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674117/how-do-i-parse-a-csv-file-to-grab-the-column-names-first-then-the-rows-that-rela)

For reading it all at once you can use:

```
$csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file("file1.csv",FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
$keys = array_shift($csv);
```

To turn all the rows into a nice associative array you could then apply:

```
foreach ($csv as $i=>$row) {
    $csv[$i] = array_combine($keys, $row);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that question,too. However, that does not work because the delimiter of the csv-file is a semicollon ; not a comma, so I need to use fgetcsv() because I can specify the delimiter.

Comment: It won't work because your file uses semicolons?  In the comments there was also this: how to use a different separator: $file = file("file1.csv",FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES); $csv = array_map("str_getcsv",$file, array_fill(0, count($file), ';'));