# Amazon MWS GetReport display in Bootstrap PHP

Tags: php, amazon-mws, amazon-marketplace, mws

I have created a page using GetReport with a Settlement ID.

So far I'm able to get a data from Amazon Seller, but i am trying to figure out how to turn the report into a tidy table.

Here is my code:

```
function invokeGetReport(MarketplaceWebService_Interface $service, $request)  {
  try {
      $response = $service->getReport($request);
        echo ("<table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-responsive'>\n");
        echo ("<thead>");
        echo ("<tr> ");
        echo ("<th >Settlement ID</th> ");
        echo ("<td>");
        echo ("Settlement ID Report display here");
        echo ("</td></tr>");
        echo ("<tr> ");
        echo ("<th>GetReportResponse\n</th> ");
        echo ("<td>");
        if ($response->isSetGetReportResult()) {
          $getReportResult = $response->getGetReportResult(); 
          echo ("            GetReport");
        echo ("</td></tr>");
      }
        //Report Content
        echo ("<tr> ");
        echo ("<th>Settlement ID</th> ");
        echo ("<td>");
        echo (stream_get_contents($request->getReport()) . "\n");
        echo ("</td></tr>");    
      } catch (MarketplaceWebService_Exception $ex) {
        echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
        echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
        echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");
        echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
        echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n");
        echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
        echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $ex->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
        echo ("</td></tr>"); 
        echo ("</table>\n");
  }

}
```

As you can see:

```
stream_get_contents($request->getReport())
```

is where I pull the Settlement Report, however, I want `getReport()` to  breakdown into more details in a tidy table, at the moment it looks like this

[image]

I  was hoping for more like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Per Amazon MWS Documentation for getReport [here](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_GetReport.html)

Your function call to `$request->getReport()` returns a tab seperated file, you can turn this into an array pretty easily, and then loop over it and print them as a table, try using the PHP [str-getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) or [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function and using tab as the delimiter

If you need the headers and want to use it as an associative array, there are plenty of guides on doing that for **csv**, but not many that are specific to **tsv**, as I can't tell much from your code as i'm unfamiliar with your specific library you're using, I can't point you to one solution that will do that for you, but there are a few for CSV that with some tweaking you could get to work, for example:

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10181125/1932789)(stackoverflow.com), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5674169/1932789)(stackoverflow.com), and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#117692)(php.net)

Comment: First of all, Thank you for your answer. Sorry for not get back to you asap.

Comment: This page was I was using on GetReportSample.php in the PHP files that I download it from Amazon MWS.  You can see more on a code in the https://github.com/jedistev/Amazon-MWS-API. I will read about using the PHP str-getcsv or fgetcsv.